# how to instant kill an apscheduler.BlockingScheduler with ctrl+c?

Tags: python, apscheduler

BACKGROUND:
PYTHON 3.8
APSCHEDULER 3.10.1

I am using BlockingScheduler for a few cron jobs and ideally I want the scheduler process can be easily stopped using ctrl+c, so I arrange my code as follow but so far it is not working properly as I expected.

THIS IS THE SCHEDULER BASE CLASS:

```
import traceback
from typing import Any, Callable
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BlockingScheduler
from apscheduler.events import EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED, EVENT_JOB_ERROR
from utils.tool.decorator import sched_job
from utils.tool.logger import log

logger = log(__file__, "utils", warning_only=False)


class APSchedulerBase:
    def __init__(self, scheduler: Any = None, add_listener: bool = True):
        if scheduler is None:
            self.sched = BlockingScheduler(timezone="Asia/Shanghai")
            if add_listener:
                self.sched.add_listener(self.ap_listener, EVENT_JOB_ERROR | EVENT_JOB_EXECUTED)
        else:
            self.sched = scheduler

    def ap_listener(self, event):
        if event.exception == KeyboardInterrupt or event.exception == SystemExit:
            self.on_kill()
        if event.exception:
            logger.error(str(traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            pass

    def on_kill(self):
        logger.warning("Scheduler Exit.")
        self.sched.shutdown(wait=False)

    def register_task(
            self, func: Callable, trigger: str,
            **kwargs
    ):
        @sched_job(
            self.sched,
            logger,
            trigger=trigger,
            **kwargs
        )
        def wrap():
            func()
        wrap()

    def start(self):
        try:
            logger.warning("Scheduler Start.")
            self.sched.start()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            self.on_kill()
```

THIS IS A SIMPLE DEMO:
ctrl+c only works when f() is about to be called.

```
import time
def f():
   print(1)
   time.sleep(10)
   print(2)
s = APSchedulerBase()
s.register_task(f, trigger='cron', hour=12, minute=30)
s.start()
```

Now the whole scheduler process can only be killed when the task is just about to be executed, if you ctrl+c when the process is dormant/waiting for the next task, nothing will happen until the next task is triggered.
So how exactly should I do to make ctrl+c instant kill?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your demo code a couple of things. First we have to define a `signal_handler` function:

```
def signal_handler(signal_number, frame, scheduler):
    # here you can add logging
    scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Then import at the top of your file `signal`:

```
import signal
```

and then just after you create the scheduler:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signum, frame: signal_handler(signum, frame, s))
```

All in all,

```
import time
import signal 

def signal_handler(signal_number, frame, scheduler):
    # here you can add logging
    scheduler.shutdown(wait=False)

def f():
   print(1)
   time.sleep(10)
   print(2)

s = APSchedulerBase()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, lambda signum, frame: signal_handler(signum, frame, s.sched))
s.register_task(f, trigger='cron', hour=12, minute=30)

s.start()
```

Why this is needed ?

When we hit CTRL+C a SIGNINT is sent to the **foreground** process. Please check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/foreground-background-process#signals). So which thread gets this signal, the thread in which scheduler is running *or* the thread in which the instance of the scheduler is created ? The answer is the latter. So since there isn't any handler for this, nothing happens.

On the other hand *scheduler process can only be killed when the task is just about to be executed*, because an exception is raised in the the thread the scheduler is running and there is an `except` statement that catches this and shutdown the scheduler

```
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
   self.on_kill()
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! Really gave me some clues. But I've tried add signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handle) in everywhere(after creating an apscheduler instance, before the instance were created, or even in the __enter__() func) before the tasks were registered. Does this have anything to do with OS? The doc you mentioned is on Linux and my code runs on win.

Comment: @damuzexlxl You are welcome ! Just updated my answer. Please give it a go once more. I would rather say no.